# find out/predict the port the router is/will be using for a given connection

Tags: networking, nat, hole-punching

I know that [ipchicken.com](http://www.ipchicken.com) will tell you your router's ip address and the port it is using for your connection. But can this information be obtained "locally"? (Without relying on a website).

What I want it for is establishing a connection between two random hosts...without a "dedicated server" in the middle. My problem is to reach through the NAT. I think the best bet is a kind of TCP hole punching, where both hosts connect somewhere and then just tell each other (it can be by phone or chat or similar) the current ip address and the port number their routers are using. It should trick the routers into forwarding the packets to the hosts, albeit coming from a different source than they originally connected to.

Is it possible to  find the port number your router is using to patch you through in a more local manner than [ipchicken.com](http://www.ipchicken.com)?
Are there any ideas on other possible approaches to this problem?

EDIT: Setting port forwarding on the router is not an option in this case, as many people (including me) do not have admin powers over their routers and I do not want to impose such a task on the "users" of my application

Answer (score 2):

The router would use a different source port for every outgoing connection, so checking based on an outgoing connection will not work for your use case.

For an incoming connection, i.e., if you want to reach a specific machine behind a NAT device (like a home router), you'll have to explicitly open up some ports on the router and set up forwarding rules. The router would then listen for incoming connections on that port and forward it to a machine:port based on the configured rule.

How you do this would depend on the specific router make/model. Search the web or logon to the admin interface and look around, it should be easy to find. However make sure you understand the security implications of opening up a port on your router!

**UPDATE based on edited question:**

Without port-forwarding and if both devices are behind NAT, your only solution is to have an intermediary server! If only one of them is behind NAT, you can have that machine initiate the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention it, but port forwarding is what I am trying to avoid (see edit).

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Stun server as the external globally reachable server.

Comment: You're recommending a Stun server for reasons that you haven't elaborated on, and your username is STUN. I'm going to be frank. I think this is spam. If it isn't, and a Stun server actually has features useful for solving this problem, edit this answer to explain.